# MacOS Catalina not able to download from the AppStore

Tags: macos, install, catalina, apple-store

First of all I went through all the similar questions in order to check if it matches with any existing question but it doesn't so I am raising this one.

Here is the problem:
I can see MacOS Catalina update available in the App Store when I am clicking on the Download button, it is stuck on calculating and the Launch Pad is showing downloading 45 Kb or sometimes some other size in KB of 8.09 GB and it is not progressing at all.

Things which I have tried and didn't worked out for me:

1. Cancelling the download, deleting it from the launch pad, trying again.
2. Deleting the default files from the Library for Software Update and restart.
3. Trying logging in from different apple ID, and verifying logging in from the same on the browser.

Some useful information:

- Internet is working flawlessly around 50 Mbps
- Other files are getting downloaded and installed properly from the App Store.
- Device Information:

  a. MacBook Pro 13-inch early 2015

  b. MacOS Sierra

  c. 84 GB space available

Please let me know for any possible solution, also I am not very keen to update to Catalina, I am fine with Mojave as well, when I tried to download Mojave from the AppStore link, the application opened and the installer was showing 15 minutes left from the initial mark and it never moved further beyond that.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm having the same issue and have tried everything.

Comment: @trevor-e Yes, I had tried freeing up space double space which is required to download the OS and somehow it resolved the issues, can you please check that how much free storage space do you have in your system?

Comment: Right after I posted this I found a different solution haha but thanks for your help. What I ended up doing was rebooting into the remote reinstall mode by holding cmd+option+r while booting up, and then it was successfully able to install Catalina from the internet.

Comment: @trevor-e Great, I'm glad that you found a solution for it swiftly. It might be useful for someone else as well.